# LED laden show helmet

Tags: raspbian, networking, hardware, audio, led

Let me start off by saying: I know very little about the interfaces that are going to be used here but I'm a steadfast study and have a programming engineering buddy that not only convinced me to post here but is willing to help as much as he can.  With that being said, I want to create a helmet to wear for my live electronica/ambient performances.  It's an anatomically correct skull with close-knit programmable LEDs.  My father is an experienced caster and we'll have no problem building the artsy-fartsy part...what I need...requires heavy nerd-flair.  I love the idea of using a Raspberry-pi to allow for tons of possibilities and impressive computing power. So the Rasp-Pi would need an I/O and an OS...I get that much, but need some pros to show me the way. Below is a haphazard sketch of the plan...and I would gladly post more detailed works the more information you gurus divulge.

NOTE: Can't post the sketch without a rep...need some help with that my brethren...

here is a link to my music hope you like, till next time:
https://soundcloud.com/cdcm-1

UPDATE: Here's the photo on Facebook...best I can do for now: https://sphotos-b-sea.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/1098080_10201291040014468_882641931_n.jpg

Comment: I am really sorry but your question is more of a discussion. On these sites you need to ask 1 question that users can try and answer. Please read the FAQ - Your question will be closed as we cannot answer it. Please ask a specific question about the Raspberry. `How to wire this LED.` or  `How to control I/O in perl.` Its an interesting project but you might want to try a forum instead if you are looking for general advice.

Comment: With that amount of LED's you will need to investigate matrix controllers. The same concept used in LED cubes! Thats all I can say. Looks like a nice helmet. Do you have blog I can follow?

Comment: Single color, or multi color leds? For multi-color I'd suggest trying to use those individually addressable LED strips. You can just chair those together, and 'talk' to them using just 4 pins (SPI) on your Pi.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you go over to the [Ada Fruit Tutorial site](http://learn.adafruit.com/). They have all sorts of stuff that can help you build what you want.